# How to add custom attribute in PDP and save that in database?

Tags: database, product-attribute, addtocart, custom-options, quote

How to add a custom attribute in Product Detail page and save it's value in quote table after the add to cart is clicked?

Comment: what type of attribute you want, is it customer or product type attribute

Comment: it is like an input field in the product page. if we type something in that field it should be saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

Here im creating a product type custom attribute

> Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\Brand.php

```
<?php
declare (strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

/**
 * Class CreateCustomAttr for Create Custom Product Attribute using Data Patch.
 */
class Brand implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * ModuleDataSetupInterface
     *
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * EavSetupFactory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'Brand',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Brand',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.attribute.custom" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/attribute/brand.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Brand:</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute/brand.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * @var Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block
 */
$product = $block->getProduct();
$attrData = $product->getData('Brand');
$blockTitle = $this->getData('title');
if (trim($attrData) !== "") : ?>
    <div class="product-full-width-section">
        <h2 class="product-section-title"><?= $blockTitle; ?></h2>
        <?php echo $attrData; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here i overrided the PDP Page and called that custom attribute

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have created all the three files in an empty module.